# Write Apache Redirect Rule?

Tags: linux, apache, webserver

How to write a apache redirect rule in apache where

http://www.example.com/8484/sdsdsd or http://www.example.com/8484/test

should redirect to www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/8484/(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R,L]
```

The `RewriteEngine On` is needed only once per VirtualHost in order to activate redirections

Comment: After /8484/ it can be anything, it needs to be single rewrite rule so that whatever after /8484/ redirected to www.example.com

Comment: http://www.example.com/travel/8484 has a 301 redirect to //travel" //travel" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">http://www.example.com//travel. need single / "/travel" like this link http://www.example.com/travel

http://www.example.com/travel/top-10/best-beaches-india/8484 has a 301 redirect to //travel/top-10/best-beaches-usa" //travel/top-10/best-beaches-usa" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">http://www.example.com//travel/top-10/best-beaches-india

In both the scenario // before travel needs to removed.

Comment: Can you create a new question please? It is difficult to read it here